# Plotting two dictionaries in one bar chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have these two dictionaries that I want to plot in the same bar chart using Matplotlib:

```
accuracy_pre = {"Random Forest": rf_accuracy_score, "Logistic Regression": log_accuracy_score, "KNN": knn_accuracy_score}

accuracy_post = {"Random Forest": gs_rf_accuracy_score, "Logistic Regression": gs_logmodel_accuracy_score, "KNN": knn_accuracy_score_iter}
```

The dictionary values are integer variables. Both dictionaries have the same keys, so there will be 6 bars in total, but those belonging to the same key will be right next to each other. 
I'm able to create two separate bar charts, but I have trouble putting them together in one. Could someone help me?

This is the code for the bar chart I already have:

```
X = np.arange(len(accuracy_pre))
plt.bar(X, accuracy_pre.values(), align='center', width=0.5)
plt.xticks(X, accuracy_pre.keys()) 
plt.title("Accuracy score - before grid search", fontsize=17)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
```

Comment: How is this a _histogram_? Do you mean bar charts?

Comment: @DYZ Yes bar chart, sorry, my mistake

Comment: Both dictionaries have the same variable name. This is not possible. One of them would be inaccessible.

Comment: @DYZ now they're both different

Comment: Whether this is a duplicate question is debatable, since plotting categorical x-coordinates is subtly different to plotting real-valued x coordinates. Unfortunately I'm not able to answer directly here, for an alternate solution you could have a look at [my answer in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805549/3041008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tweaked your code a bit to get the desired plot. Hope this helps!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sample data
accuracy_pre = {"Random Forest": 1, "Logistic Regression": 2, "KNN": 3}
accuracy_post = {"Random Forest": 4, "Logistic Regression": 5, "KNN": 6}

X = np.arange(len(accuracy_pre))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, accuracy_pre.values(), width=0.2, color='b', align='center')
ax.bar(X-0.2, accuracy_post.values(), width=0.2, color='g', align='center')
ax.legend(('Pre Accuracy','Post Accuracy'))
plt.xticks(X, accuracy_pre.keys())
plt.title("Accuracy score", fontsize=17)
plt.show()
```